# Auto resize QLabel to fit updated QTableWidget span

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt4

I have a `QTableWidget`, and I have a `QLabel` that I put inside a cell of the table using `.setCellWidget()`.
During run-time I change the span of the `QTableWidget` cell where the QLabel is, using `.setSpan()`

BUT when I change the span of the cell where the `QLabel` is, the QLabel does not resize.

Some code and screenshot below:

```
def generate_table(self):
    global gtable
    
    table = QTableWidget(20, 60)
    gtable = table
    
    def create_task(self):
    task_widget = QWidget()
    task_layout = QHBoxLayout()
    task_widget.setLayout(task_layout)
    
    task = QLabelClickable(the_task_name)
    
    task_layout.addWidget(task)
    
    gtable.setCellWidget(selected_row_column[0], selected_row_column[1], task_widget)
    
    // if I include this part of the code, everything looks fine, both cell, widget and label scale properly, as visible through background color, below line is not the problem, notice its in the same function as where I set the cell widget

    the_duration = 3    

    gtable.setSpan(selected_row, selected_column, 1, the_duration)
    
    // Below is how I change the cell span. The rrow and ccolumn are integers, basically just cell coordinates
    def save_task(self):
    gtable.setSpan(rrow, ccolumn, 1, w_dr.value())
```

(there's a ton of code all over the place so I included what I thought is relevant, let me know what other parts of the code I should include)

This is what it should look like: (this is what the first span-changing line does)

[image]

This is what it looks like: (this is what the last line does)

[image]

My question is, How do I resize the QLabel / QWidget to auto fit the cell's updated size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the first span as correct because it's applied in the same event loop that would update the geometries of the view.

Spanning does not automatically do that (which could be a bug), so the solution is to use [`updateGeometries()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#updateGeometries), which:

> Updates the geometry of the child widgets of the view.

Which means that *all* widgets of the view will be correctly resized and updated, including scroll bars and cell widgets.

```
    def save_task(self):
        gtable.setSpan(rrow, ccolumn, 1, w_dr.value())
        gtable.updateGeometries()
```

<sup>A **very important** suggestion: avoid using globals, they are not handy as one would think, and in fact the often cause problems and bugs that are difficult to track; use instance members instead (eg. `self.gtable`).</sup>

Comment: The reason I'm using globals is becaue I need this variable accessible in multiple different classes.
So you're saying its there's a way to pass gtable around the classes without globals and it'd be better rigth?
Thanks btw!

Comment: @VadimTatarnikov using globals per se is not prohibited (actually, they are important, as long as used with awareness). The fact is that they are too often used for the wrong reasons and poor project implementation. If you need to share an object between classes (or better, instances) you should ask yourself if you do need that object or its properties, and how/when/why those properties are required. Consider that objects should be self contained and not directly access other *foreign* (not "child") objects but communicate with them (that's what signals and slots are for).